# Query only returns groups that have users

Tags: c#, wmi

The code below returns the list of groups and associated members on a machine. Why does it only return populated groups. For example create a new user group on your machine and it will not be returned on this query. However if you add a user to the user group it will return in the query. Is there a fix to the query?

**C# Code**

```
var sGroupName = "";
var sUsername = "";
ManagementObjectSearcher searchresult = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_GroupUser");


foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searchresult.Get())
{
         sGroupName = queryObj["GroupComponent"].ToString().Split(new[] { "Name=" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last().Trim('"');
         sUsername = queryObj["PartComponent"].ToString().Split(new[] { "Name=" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last().Trim('"');
}
```

Comment: While I'm not experienced with this namespace, it would occur to me that selecting from a 'GroupUser' table would be just that-- users. There's most likely a 'Group' table that holds the groups, themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var searchResult = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Group");
```

Comment: that only returns the group names. i am looking for a WMI query that returns groups and associated members INCLUDING groups that are empty. The "INCLUDING groups that are empty" piece is not returned.

Comment: @user1438082 So what would be easiest for you, would be to select all of the groups using the Win32_Group table, and then for each group, select any users from the Win32_GroupUser table using a WHERE clause to match only those in the group. Implementation is up to you, but this process would give you what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Yes - However i was hoping that there would be a simple modification to the existing query to get me the data i need.